# Got string Url but the url have "\/".How to get each correct value in string like array type swift3

Tags: ios, swift, string, nsstring

I got a string from server,but the url string looks strange, and it also like array type. I don't know how to get each value. Sorry I am beginner.Thanks.

```
let string:String = "[\"http:\/\/aaa.com\/user\/head\/111.jpg?1495612713419\",\"http:\/\/aaa.com\/user\/head\/222.jpg?1496215823622\",\"http:\/\/aaa.com\/user\/head\/333.jpg?1495251220764\",\"http:\/\/aaa.com\/user\/head\/444.jpg?1495773694237\",\"http:\/\/aaa.com\/user\/head\/555.jpg?1495597839001\"]"

let tempArr = string.components(separatedBy: ",")
var stringArr = Array<String>()

for a in tempArr {
    var b = a.replacingOccurrences(of: "\"", with: "")
    b = b.replacingOccurrences(of: "[", with: "")
    b = b.replacingOccurrences(of: "]", with: "")
    stringArr.append(b)
}
print(stringArr)
```

print log

```
["http:\\/\\/aaa.com\\/user\\/head\\/111.jpg?1495612713419", "http:\\/\\/aaa.com\\/user\\/head\\/222.jpg?1496215823622", "http:\\/\\/aaa.com\\/user\\/head\\/333.jpg?1495251220764", "http:\\/\\/aaa.com\\/user\\/head\\/444.jpg?1495773694237", "http:\\/\\/aaa.com\\/user\\/head\\/555.jpg?1495597839001"]
```

Comment: it is array of url

Comment: The very first statement `let string:String . . .\"]"` is not a valid . plz . correct it .

Comment: it's a string correct. just it like array.

Comment: like let string = "[\"aaa\", \"bbb\", \"ccc\", \"ddd\", \"eee\", \"fff\", \"ggg\"]"

Comment: let string:[String]=[\"aaa\", \"bbb\", \"ccc\", \"ddd\", \"eee\", \"fff\", \"ggg\"] is right way

Comment: its a array and you can access through index

Answer (score 0):

The server is sending the url of images that converted into the string and string have by default property to add \ in Json so just convert the string into the url the \ will auto remove.
eg. 
let url = NSURL(string: urlstring)
print("the url = (url)")

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The \ is added as escaping character while the string is encoded to JSON and it seems you are directly using the JSON string without decoding it first. How are you getting this result? are you using Alamofire?. Please let me know to help you further.

```
 func fetchMyImages() {
    let url = "some url to call the image api"
    let request = Alamofire.request(url)
    request.validate().responseJSON { [unowned self] (response) in
        switch response.result {
        case .success(let result):
            self.doSomething(with: result) //the result is Any object
        case .failure(let error):
            print("Oh my Error: \(error)")
        }
    }
}
```

This will give you the JSON decoded object and then you can cast it appropriately to Dictionary if it is Dictionary or Array if it is Array

Comment: Yes, I use alamofire and swiftyJson.

Comment: I dont know where use decode. I use decode func but it seen not working.

Comment: maybe this can help. I've edited my post with some snippet